# ASP.NET 4 Calendar control doesn't show SelectedDate

Tags: c#, asp.net, calendar

I have an ASP.NET 4 calendar display problem. I want to programmatically set the calendar. So, I put this code in the `void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)` function:

```
Calendar1.SelectedDate = DateTime.Parse("2011-07-25");
```

it works fine. But, it displays the current month of the calendar (August) instead of the date I selected (July). I have to select back one month to see the date that I programmatically assigned.

[image][image]

What should i do?

Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to set the [VisibleDate](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.calendar.visibledate.aspx) property to the month that you want it to show =)

Answer (score 1):

There is a gotcha that you should be aware of.

If you set the selected date to `DateTime.Now` or something based on it such as `DateTime.Now.AddYears(1)` then the selected date will **not** be highlighted in the calendar even though it is selected.

You need to remove the time component using `DateTime.Now.Date` so that the calendar can do the comparison correctly when rendering. It took me a bit of debugging in the `DayRenderEventHandler` to figure that out.

I hope that somebody finds it useful.